# C# update problems

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got this sqlException :

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
newConnection.ConnectionM();
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Update Cost SET ActualAmount=@actualamount,FlagAdjustment=@flag, Date=@date where ProjectID=@projectid, PropertyID=@propertyid, CostCategoryID=@costcategoryid";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualamount", textBoxAmount.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", flag);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePickerDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid", ProjectID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@propertyid", PropertyID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costcategoryid", CostCatID);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
```

Comment: [Read the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql) on how `WHERE` conditions are specified. It's not with commas.

Comment: If you have a *SQL* exception you should post a *SQL* question and actually try the statement to ensure it's correct. In this particular case though, a SQL tutorial would be more appropriate

Comment: Please, rewrite your question with correct tags and a valid title (C# problems is not a valid title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas in where condition should be separated with **and** or **OR** or whatever condition you want to apply.

I have used this with **and** condition as below:

```
 newConnection.ConnectionM();
                SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Update Cost SET ActualAmount=@actualamount,FlagAdjustment=@flag, Date=@date where ProjectID=@projectid and PropertyID=@propertyid and CostCategoryID=@costcategoryid";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualamount", textBoxAmount.Text);
```

Comment: Op has very basic syntax error in his query, which means he is a newbie.  Don't confuse a newbie, why *`it should be separated with and` why not `OR`. Please avoid confusing answers.

Comment: I have updated the answer @un-lucky

Comment: I also would like to add one thing that, while we are thinking not to confuse a newbie, we should not downvote his\her question in this case. Instead just close it. @un-lucky. Just a thought.

Comment: Better place for this question will be in meta. But one think I don't see any downvoted answers here

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant we should not downvote OP's question. OP has got almost 6 downvotes, which is wrong @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

i think you should write correct syntax

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Cost SET ActualAmount=@actualamount,FlagAdjustment=@flag, Date=@date where ProjectID=@projectid and PropertyID=@propertyid and CostCategoryID=@costcategoryid";
```

i hope it is useful for you